# What is the relationship between emissivity $\varepsilon$ and the imaginary part of relative permittivity constant $\epsilon^{''}_{\rm r}$ if any?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, dielectric, absorption, photon-emission

In terms of the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) a body that does not absorb all incident radiation emits less total energy than a black body and is characterized by an emissivity $0<\varepsilon <1$ such that:
$$J=\varepsilon\sigma T^{4}$$
The definition of all parameters in the above equation may be seen in the link above. On the other hand, we know the power (per unit volume) dissipated during dielectric or RF heating is governed by the following [formula](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/dissipated-power):
$$P_{V}=\omega\epsilon_{0}\epsilon^{''}_{\rm r}E^{2}_{\rm rms}$$
where $P_{V}$ is the dissipated power per unit volume, $\epsilon_{0}$  is the permittivity of vacuum, $E_{\rm rms}$ is the electric field strength in V/m, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the incident wave and $\epsilon^{''}_{\rm r}$ is the imaginary part of the relative dielectric constant for the material absorbing radiation. What is the quantitative relationship between $\varepsilon$ and $\epsilon^{''}_{\rm r}$? Thank you!

Comment: Yes they are related. Given a precise form of $\epsilon_r''$ a specific value for the emissivity is calculated.

Comment: Be aware that $\epsilon_r''$ is usually a function of the frequency so it is not like you can plot the emissivity as a function of  $\epsilon_r''$ or something like that. The emissivity results from integrating over all frequencies.

Comment: @Mauricio that's not a comment... That's an answer! Please write up an answer rather than answering in short as a comment